# How can I make waveHeight return based on a Vector3 position entered from another script?

Tags: unity, c#

I have this script which calculates `waveHeight` based on a `raycastHit` point.

Right now it only casts the `raycastHit` from `observer.transform.position`, so therefore it only ever returns `waveHeight` from `observer`'s position. Instead, I need the functionality of having this script return `waveHeight` from any position queried from an outside script. Therefore, I started to create the public float `WaterHeightAtPosition` which takes in a `Vector3 position`, but I don't know how to continue coding this from there.

And so, how can I make `public float WaterHeightAtPosition` return `waveHeight` based on any outside gameObject's position? That way, if an outside script enters something like `GetWaterHeight.WaterHeightAtPosition(transform.position)`, then it will indeed return the correct number based on that outside gameObject's transform?

Thank you for any help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetWaterHeight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject observer;
    public LayerMask objectLayer;

    public float rayHeight = 20f;
    RaycastHitRenderer hit;
    Ray ray;

    public float waveHeight = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        ray = new Ray(observer.transform.position, Vector3.up);
        Debug.DrawRay(observer.transform.position, Vector3.up * rayHeight, Color.red);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        print("This is it: " + waveHeight);

        waveHeight = hit.point.y;

        if (transform.position.y < waveHeight)
        {
            if (SuperRaycast.Raycast(ray, out hit, 9000f, objectLayer))
            {
                print("Floating");
            
                Debug.Log(hit.renderer.name + "      " + hit.point.y);
            }
        }
    }

    public float WaterHeightAtPosition(Vector3 position)
    {
        return waveHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [Transform.TransformVector()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformVector.html) which converts a Vector3 into a position in world space? Alternatively theres [InverseTransformVector()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformVector.html) which converts world -> local.